# uniprocessor or multiprocessor

Tags: unix, kernel, pthreads, processors

On unix, how could we know whether the system is multiprocessor or uniprocessor?

Comment: Does a Pentium 4 with hyperthreading count as uniprocessor or multiprocessor?

Comment: unix HPUX and also i tried on AIX

Comment: i cant find any cpuinfo file in /proc/.so does it mean that there is no way we cant find the answer on unix?

Comment: There _is_ a POSIX way to do this, it lies in the thread affinity stuff, and I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some times we have to answer owr own question :)

On Solaris run the command

```
/usr/sbin/psrinfo -v|grep "Status of processor"|wc -l
```

On AIX run the command

```
lsdev -C|grep Process|wc -l
```

On HP-UX run the following commands (requires superuser privileges):

```
P=`echo processor_count/D | adb -k /stand/vmunix /dev/mem |tail -1|awk '{print $2}'` echo "The number of processors on `hostname` = $P"
```

On Tru64 run the command

```
 /usr/sbin/psrinfo -v|grep "Status of processor"|wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i 'processor' | wc -l
```

Or even

```
 dmesg | grep -i cpu
```

Look out for "Brought up x processors" in the last one

Comment: procfs is pretty much only a Linux thing. You won't see it on many other systems. FreeBSD for example only has it if the Linux compat stuff is installed.

Comment: Yes johannes. u seem to be right. i cant find any cpuinfo file in /proc/.so does it mean that there is no way we cant find the answer on unix?

Comment: -1 since i have tagged for only unix and linux answer doesnt help me

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it applies to Unix as well, but for Linux, from command line, see here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/display-number-of-processors-on-linux/

Comment: procfs is pretty much only a Linux thing. You won't see it on many other systems. FreeBSD for example only has it if the Linux compat stuff is installed.

Comment: i cant find any cpuinfo file in /proc/.so does it mean that there is no way we cant find the answer on unix?