# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, get, cpu

I've made a console application in VS 2010 in order to get the number of cores:
This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
        FILE * fp;
        char res[128];
        fp = popen("/bin/cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep -c '^processor'","r");
        fread(res, 1, sizeof(res)-1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
        cout << "number of core: " << res[0] << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

And this is what it shows:

```
**1>------ Build started: Project: project_scs, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 6/5/2014 8:01:03 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\project_scs.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  project_scs.cpp
1>c:\users\myUser\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project_scs\project_scs\project_scs.cpp(1): warning C4627: '#include <iostream>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\users\myUser\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project_scs\project_scs\project_scs.cpp(2): warning C4627: '#include "stdio.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\users\myUser\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project_scs\project_scs\project_scs.cpp(9): error C3861: 'popen': identifier not found
1>c:\users\myUser\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project_scs\project_scs\project_scs.cpp(10): error C3861: 'fread': identifier not found
1>c:\users\myUser\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project_scs\project_scs\project_scs.cpp(11): error C3861: 'fclose': identifier not found
1>c:\users\myUser\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project_scs\project_scs\project_scs.cpp(12): error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\myUser\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project_scs\project_scs\project_scs.cpp(12): error C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.08
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========**
```

What is the problem and what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` should appear in the very 1st line before any other `#include` directives.

Comment: thanks. Now there is just 1 error left:  error C3861: 'popen': identifier not found

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619198/how-to-get-number-of-cores-in-win32

Comment: `/bin/cat /proc/cpuinfo` Did you type in that command in a Windows command prompt to see if it actually works?

Comment: well, I know now that it is for Linux. I searched on Internet and I've found that for getting CPUINFO is used "C:\>wmic cpu get caption" which doesn't work either. Do you know which is the actual path that must be used? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many issues really, but your main one is that you are using precompiled headers incorrectly. Check MSDN for more info on that.

Also `popen()` is not part of the Win32 API. It is in Posix but you are not using that. You might want to checkout `_popen` though:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thankyou for the advice. What can I use to replace popen() ?

Comment: @user3677169 - See the updated answer. Also upvote my answer if you want to thank me :)

Comment: I see that there is used _popen instead of popen. Which still doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading your errors: `1>c:\users\myUser\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project_scs\project_scs\project_scs.cpp(2): warning C4627: '#include "stdio.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use`.

Then also consider that the Linux approach (reading `/proc`) is unlikely to work on a system that can run an executable created by Visual Studio.